# How to concatenate text to rtf formatted string

Tags: c#, string, datatable, concatenation, rtf

I have a SQL Server table which has a column of SQL data type *text*. This column contains rtf formatted text.

I read the table as a DataTable.

I'm trying to get the column value as a string and append it with additional text.

```cs
    string rtfContent = SourceRow["TEXT"].ToString();
    rtfContent += "more text";
```

But somehow, the string does not change. The value *more text* is not being added.

I tried all possible types of concatenations (that I am aware of):

```cs
    string str = string.Concat(rtfContent, "more text");
    str = rtfContent + "more text";
    str = $"{rtfContent} more text";
    str = string.Format("{0}{1}", rtfContent, "more text");
```

I can add text **before** the actual rtf string, e.g.:

```cs
    string str = "more text" + rtfContent;
```

But in my case I need both options.

This is my **rtfContent**:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial Unicode MS;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\tx568\tx1136\tx1704\tx2272\tx2840\tx3408\tx3976\tx4544\tx5112\tx5680\f0\fs20 Produktbeschreibung:\par
\b Fahrzeugleitung nach DIN 72551\par
\b0 Typ FLRY\par
Isolationsreduziert\par
2,5 mm\'b2\par
5, 25, 100 m Ring\par
rot\par
Hersteller: FREI\par
Verpackungsgewicht: 0.649kg\par
RoHS: konform\par
\par
}
```

In Visual Studio while debugging:

```cs
    //rtfContent: "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1031{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial Unicode MS;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\tx568\\tx1136\\tx1704\\tx2272\\tx2840\\tx3408\\tx3976\\tx4544\\tx5112\\tx5680\\f0\\fs20 Produktbeschreibung:\\par\r\n\\b Fahrzeugleitung nach DIN 72551\\par\r\n\\b0 Typ FLRY\\par\r\nIsolationsreduziert\\par\r\n2,5 mm\\'b2\\par\r\n5, 25, 100 m Ring\\par\r\nrot\\par\r\nHersteller: FREI\\par\r\nVerpackungsgewicht: 0.649kg\\par\r\nRoHS: konform\\par\r\n\\par\r\n}\r\n\0"
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working as expected? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some failing value for `rtfContent`  so we can recreate. (I'm certain strings are not broken in general.)

Comment: Sure, sorry that I missed that. I have added one example of **rtfContent** in my initial question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation I found out that the rtf string I retrieved from the database is terminated with `"\0"` at the end of the string which prevents me from adding any more characters to the string (or at least not showing them visually).

I got it to work as follows:

```cs
string rtfContent = SourceRow["TEXT"].ToString();
rtfContent = rtfContent.TrimEnd('\0');
rtfContent += "more text";
// result: "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1031{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial Unicode MS;}} \\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\tx568\\tx1136\\tx1704\\tx2272\\tx2840\\tx3408\\tx3976\\tx4544\\tx5112\\tx5680\\f0\\fs20 Produktbeschreibung:\\par \\b Fahrzeugleitung nach DIN 72551\\par \\b0 Typ FLRY\\par Isolationsreduziert\\par 2,5 mm\\'b2\\par 5, 25, 100 m Ring\\par rot\\par Hersteller: FREI\\par Verpackungsgewicht: 0.649kg\\par RoHS: konform\\par \\par }  more text"
```